# PHP CURL script runs but it does not set the cookie

Tags: php, curl, cookies

Im trying to set a cookie through PHP CURL for more than twenty four hour for no avail.

Before i have been setting cookies in my browser by adding them as parameters in a url as shown below

```
http://localhost/setc.php?userid=123&amp;panelid=1
```

but now i need to set the cookie when i run a script(setcookie.php)

below is the latest of various types of code that i tried.

setcookie.php

```
$c = curl_init('http://localhost/atst.php?userid=628929&panelid=1');

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'userid=123; panelid=1');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$page = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

it still does not create the cookie, can anybody help out

**P.S : if you guys too cant figure this out at least give me a hint/guide on how to set a simple cookie without any complications**

Comment: Have you missed or forgot to add `$c = curl_init(); `?

Comment: i forgot its there in the original code

Answer (score 0):

The cookiejar is only saved when you close the curl handle using curl_close($ch).

From the manual:

CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE The name of the file containing the cookie data. The cookie file can be in Netscape format, or just plain HTTP-style headers dumped into a file. If the name is an empty string, no cookies are loaded, but cookie handling is still enabled.

CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR The name of a file to save all internal cookies to when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

```
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp/", "CURLCOOKIE");
        $BASEURL='http://localhost/openx/www/api/json/index.php/main/authenticate/';
        $POSTFIELDS='username='.$username.'&password='.$password.'';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookieFileName");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://localhost/openx/www/api/json/index.php/main/authenticate/');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POSTFIELDS);

        ob_start();      // prevent any output
        $result=curl_exec ($ch); // execute the curl command
        ob_end_clean();  // stop preventing output

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: do you have write access to the directory you are trying to save the file?

Comment: thanks for the description btw... i should replace my url with the $BASEURL given here right

Comment: Yes please check this answer as green.

Comment: sure mate... but im currently working this out btw can you please exaplain this "/tmp/cookieFileName" after the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR

Comment: CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR use for create cookie name in tmp folder

Comment: i dont want to save it in a tmp folder,, i just want to set it in the browser and also the $POSTFIELDS are not required in my case isnt it

Comment: hey tmp folder will be in browser only.